# Oneplus 2 Stuck in boot animation after root

Tags: root-access, boot, boot-loop, operating-system, oneplus-two

so I recently tried to root my oneplus 2 to be able to flash cm13 onto it. I followed the guide oneplus provided on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZaajUEybNM) exactly and got the same results for everything except that my phone does not boot. The only differences between my phone and their guide were that I had a newer operating system (Oxygen OS 3.0.1) and I flashed the latest version for everything, also I went for the Stable version of Super SU instead of the beta. I understand that he said it would take a little time to boot, but I am assuming he doesn't mean 5+ hours.

I am still able to boot into recovery (TWRP) and fastboot but not the OS. I tried wiping the phone and installing Super SU again, but no luck. I am stuck here and don't know what to do next. Any help would be amazing and extremely appreciated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48103/discussion-on-question-by-user195317-oneplus-2-stuck-in-boot-animation-after-roo).

Answer (score 1):

According to this [thread](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/return-op2-to-100-stock-unbrick-soft-bricked-op2-oxygenos-2-1-1-fastboot-images.388967/) on the OnePlus forum:
To return to full stock after a soft brick:

- Download the Fastboot images [here](https://mega.nz/#!itR00ZaI!gJ6T0jgqfZaIF9NLlCzWj4LIGMMhCw8m8owFdeB_2B4) (,it restores to OOS 2.1.1)
- Extract the zip file to anywhere you'd like
- Boot the phone in Fastboot mode (Volume up + power button)
- Connect the phone to the PC
- Open the unzipped folder and run the file with the .bat extension (Windows) or a file with name *flash-all*

The above method doesn't clear the data partition, to clear it:

- Download the userdata.img from [here](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=24052804347833307) amd flash it using `fastboot flash userdata userdata_64.img`

And you need a working ADB/Fastboot environment.

Comment: so I dont need to use twrp?

Comment: No, since you'll use a computer.

Comment: I am not able to access the userdata_64.img file because it is private, it is denying me access... Do I need it?

Answer (score 1):

This solution seems to work flawlessly

- Download this [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9IqSEI0OM37RTM5M09Ib180U0E/view?usp=sharing)
- Boot the phone in Fastboot (Volume up + Power)
- Tape the following:

  fastboot erase persist

  fastboot flash persist persist.img

  fastboot reboot

This seems to work for them. You need the official TWRP ([Download](https://dl.twrp.me/oneplus2/))

Source : [XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-2/help/stuck-bootlogo-flashing-cm13-rom-t3315823/page1)